# How i can access this Json from my AsyncTask?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I'm trying to retrieve data from Json Like below :

```
{
    comments: [
      {
          id: 78,
          comment_user_id: 81,
          comment_is_approve: 1,
          comment_ads_id: 373,
          comment_text: "commmmmmeeeent here ",
          created_at: "2017-03-19 08:32:17",
          updated_at: "2017-03-19 08:32:17",
          user: {
              id: 81,
              first_name: "name",
              last_name: "",
              age: "",
              email: "l@mail.com",
              telephone: "234234234",
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my `asyncTask()` :

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url + 373, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        //Log.d("All Comments: ", json.toString());

        try {
            JSONArray comments = json.getJSONArray("comments");

            // looping through All Comments
            for (int i = 0; i < comments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = comments.getJSONObject(i);




                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String commentText = c.getString("comment_text");
                String name = "";
                String phone = "";

                Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground Items: " + id + " , "+ commentText);

                    //Loop through All user details
                    JSONArray arrUser = c.getJSONArray("user");

                int  l = 0;
                        JSONObject user = arrUser.getJSONObject(l++);
                        name = user.getString("first_name");
                        phone = user.getString("telephone");
                        // creating new HashMap

                        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground Items: " + name +", " + commentText + ", " + phone);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList




                mapItems = new HashMap<>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                mapItems.put("id", id);
                mapItems.put("first_name", name);
                mapItems.put("comment_text", commentText);
                mapItems.put("telephone", phone);
                contactList.add(mapItems);
```

I can get commentText and id , but i can't get any data from user array ? 
should i add parantethes to users or how i can achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `user` is not an array..it is a JsonObject

try this:

```
JSONObject User = c.getJSONObject("user");

String id = User.getString("id");
String first_name = User.getString("first_name");
```

or modify your json response to return an array instead.

Also your JSON response is invalid.

this is the valid JSON response:

```
 {
    "comments": [{
        "id": 78,
        "comment_user_id": 81,
        "comment_is_approve": 1,
        "comment_ads_id": 373,
        "comment_text": "commmmmmeeeent here ",
        "created_at": "2017-03-19 08:32:17",
        "updated_at": "2017-03-19 08:32:17",
        "user": {
            "id": 81,
            "first_name": "name",
            "last_name": "",
            "age": "",
            "email": "l@mail.com",
            "telephone": "234234234"    //remove comma here
        }
    }]
}
```

you can check valid JSON from [HERE](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: did u validate you JSON ? it will work if the json is valid..you user object contain an extra comma...

Comment: i think i have a problem with something else ,,,

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply nested structure like this

```
        JSONArray arrUser1 = c.getJSONArray("user");            
        for (int j = 0; j < arrUser1.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject c1 = arrUser1.getJSONObject(j);
            name = c1.getString("first_name");
            phone = c1.getString("telephone");

            mapItems = new HashMap<>();                
            mapItems.put("id", id);
            mapItems.put("first_name", name);
            mapItems.put("comment_text", commentText);
            mapItems.put("telephone", phone);
            contactList.add(mapItems);

           }
```

Comment: i tried this before  but the `mapItems` can't reach  strings in 2nd For loop.

Comment: you get name and phone value means check your HashMap initialization code

Comment: `HashMap<String, String> mapItems;`

Answer (score 0):

User is a **JSONObject** in this case. I am not sure why you have used a **JSONArray**.

This should be enough.

```
JSONObject user = c.getJSONObject("user");
name = user.getString("first_name");
phone = user.getString("telephone");
```

Comment: you can't define `JSONObject` and get `c.getJSONArray` this is illegal !